# How to extend geom_line with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Firsty, I am sorry for the "not so appropriate" title for my question. I have the following data frame (`df`):

```
      TIMESTAMP GPSSpeed_kmh accel jerk
863 2018-11-10 13:37:59         36.4  -0.3  0.0
864 2018-11-10 13:38:00         35.3  -0.3 -0.1
865 2018-11-10 13:38:01         34.2  -0.4  0.0
866 2018-11-10 13:38:02         32.8  -0.4 -0.4
867 2018-11-10 13:38:03         31.3  -0.8 -0.4
868 2018-11-10 13:38:04         28.4  -1.2 -0.1
869 2018-11-10 13:38:05         24.1  -1.3  0.6
870 2018-11-10 13:38:06         19.4  -0.7  0.3
871 2018-11-10 13:38:07         16.9  -0.4  0.3
872 2018-11-10 13:38:08         15.5  -0.1  0.2
873 2018-11-10 13:38:09         15.1   0.1  0.4
874 2018-11-10 13:38:10         15.5   0.5  0.4
875 2018-11-10 13:38:11         17.3   0.9  0.1
876 2018-11-10 13:38:12         20.5   1.0 -0.4
877 2018-11-10 13:38:13         24.1   0.6 -0.4
878 2018-11-10 13:38:14         26.3   0.2  0.0
879 2018-11-10 13:38:15         27.0   0.2  0.0
880 2018-11-10 13:38:16         27.7   0.2  0.0
881 2018-11-10 13:38:17         28.4   0.2  0.5
882 2018-11-10 13:38:18         29.2   0.7  0.0
883 2018-11-10 13:38:19         31.7   0.7 -0.4
884 2018-11-10 13:38:20         34.2   0.3   NA
885 2018-11-10 13:38:21         35.3    NA   NA
```

The column `GPSpeed_kmh` is primary data. Acceleration (`accel` in m/s^2) column was calculated as the derivative of the `GPSSpeed_kmh` over time and `jerk` (in m/s^3) column was calculated as the derivative of the acceleration over time. I used the following code to plot speed, acceleration and jerk over time:

```
    data.m<-melt (df, measure.vars = c("GPSSpeed_kmh", "accel", "jerk"))
    ggplot(data.m, aes(TIMESTAMP, value)) +
      geom_line(col = "red") + 
      geom_smooth() +
      facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y") +
      scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M:%S", tz="Europe/Athens"))
```

and the result is the following:
[image]
As you can see, `GPSSpeed_kmh` line lasts longer over time comparatively with `accel` and `jerk`. It is reasonable in a sense that `accel` and `jerk` column have `NA`s in the last rows. I want to make `accel` and `jerk` plots over time to finish at the same `TIMESTAMP` as `GPSSpeed_kmh` plot does. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make-up or lose data. The act of calculating the derivative (using `diff`, perhaps?) will always produce fewer observations than the original field. So either (1) extrapolate on `speed` for two units and do not plot those two data points on speed; or (2) cut all observations down by two, perhaps with `head(., n=-2)`. Personally, I'd prefer to lose some data than inject a biased prediction, but that's just me.

Comment: How do you imagine doing this? There’s simply no data for these time points.